Helm deployment of canal broken on RKE2 v1.29.4+rke2r1
I just did a fresh install of RKE2 (v1.29.4+rke2r1) today and a few pods are broken. I deleted one of the stuck pods named helm-install-rke2-canal-tv2sf thinking that might help (might cause it to respawn) but nope.
Two of my three control-plane,etcd,master nodes are in state NotReady. Should I try to redeploy the helm chart for canal? How do I find its name?
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-coredns-n9xtk                        0/1     Completed               0               119m
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-ingress-nginx-r4q4j                  0/1     Completed               0               115m
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-metrics-server-r9dt8                 0/1     Completed               0               119m
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-snapshot-controller-crd-d4tdt        0/1     Completed               0               119m
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-snapshot-controller-jkpq4            0/1     Completed               2               119m
kube-system      helm-install-rke2-snapshot-validation-webhook-r6vwx    0/1     Completed               0               119m
kube-system      rke2-canal-4vdnl                                       0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   7 (4m36s ago)    19m
kube-system      rke2-canal-hf7vr                                       0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   24 (2m26s ago)   114m

on a worker node, the rke2-agent service logs says,
Jul 13 23:01:20 tz3 rke2[1824]: time="2024-07-13T23:01:20Z" level=info msg="Connecting to proxy" url="wss://192.168.10.103:9345/v1-rke2/connect"
Jul 13 23:01:20 tz3 rke2[1824]: time="2024-07-13T23:01:20Z" level=info msg="Remotedialer connected to proxy" url="wss://192.168.10.103:9345/v1-rke2/connect"
Jul 13 23:02:17 tz3 rke2[1824]: time="2024-07-13T23:02:17Z" level=error msg="Remotedialer proxy error; reconecting..." error="read tcp 192.168.10.104:53506->192.168.10.98:9345: read: connection reset by peer" url="wss://192.168.10.98:9345/v1-rke2/connect"
Jul 13 23:02:18 tz3 rke2[1824]: time="2024-07-13T23:02:18Z" level=info msg="Connecting to proxy" url="wss://192.168.10.98:9345/v1-rke2/connect"
Jul 13 23:02:18 tz3 rke2[1824]: time="2024-07-13T23:02:18Z" level=info msg="Remotedialer connected to proxy" url="wss://192.168.10.98:9345/v1-rke2/connect"

Not sure what to do next. Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.
